# React Native Clear TextInput on onKeyPress

Tags: react-native

In my React Native app I want to clear the TextInput when the user hits the comma button. This will never clear the input. However, if I assign the same functionality to a Button  component then it will work:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'

const COMMA = ','

const AddTags = () => {
  const [ tagValue, setTagValue ] = useState('')
  const tRef = React.createRef()

  // THIS WONT WORK
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.key === COMMA) {
      tRef.current.clear()
      setTagValue('')
    }
  }

  // THIS DOES WORK
  const buttonPress = () => {
    // You dont need both, either will work
    tRef.current.clear()
    setTagValue('')
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Add Tags</Text>
      <Button onPress={buttonPress} title="Clear" />
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={setTagValue}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyDown}
        ref={tRef}
        value={tagValue}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default AddTags
```

Not sure why it won't clear onKeyPress but it will when the button is pressed. The code is exactly the same..

Comment: Is this returning `true`: `event.nativeEvent.key === COMMA` ?

Comment: Yes. I actually solved the issue. I can do the check for comma in `onChangeText` and using `onKeyPress` in unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking it over more I realized that using onKeyPress with onChangeText is overkill. I can simply use `onKeyPress` to check for commas:

```
const testChange = (e) => {
  if (e.includes(',')) {
    setTagValue('')
  } else {
    setTagValue(e)
  }
}

<TextInput
  ...
  onChangeText={(e) => testChange(e)}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

change `createRef` to `useRef`

```
const tRef = React.useRef()
```